# Deployed react app(with react-routing) on nginx server giving error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-hooks, react-router, httpserver

I have deployed my react app on the Nginx server and on the console it is giving me these errors -

[image]

I get these errors while rerouting the page to a different page (using react routers)

On my local machine, no errors are coming, and everything is working as expected. I ran my build folder on my local machine using HTTP-server to validate if my build files have issues, but it is also running absolutely fine. I am not able to debug it and not sure really what is causing this issue when I deploy the files on Nginx server. Any pointers or ideas?

This is my react-router code -

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/admin" element={<AdminPanel />}>
            <Route path="/admin/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/clients" element={<Clients/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/members" element={<Members/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/datasets" element={<Dataset/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/schema" element={<Schema/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/toolconstants" element={<ToolConstants/>} />
            <Route path="/admin/roles" element={<Roles/>} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/annotation" element={<AnnotationDashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

From `/` I am routing to `/admin/dashboard`

Deployment team is deploying this app to nginx server where it is throwing these errors.

Below is the Nginx config file -

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;              
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors appear to imply that `React` is null. Can you edit the post to include your routing code, and anything else that is using these React hooks, as part of a [mcve]? Can you also share where/how you are deploying the app, and how it is being served to clients?

Comment: *What* is actually being deployed out on a server though, and *how* is it deployed and the server serving up the app? Check the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to get a general idea what different setups/configurations different server environments need in order to host and server a React SPA.